# Sizing scatter plot point mean proportional to sample size

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, point, sample

I am creating a scatter plot using ggplot2 and would like to size my point means proportional to the sample size used to calculate the mean. This is my code, where I used `fun.y` to calculate the mean by group `Trt`:

```
branch1 %>%
ggplot() + aes(x=Branch, y=Flow_T, group=Trt, color=Trt) +
stat_summary(aes(group=Trt), fun.y=mean, geom="point", size=)
```

I am relatively new to R, but my guess is to use `size` in the `aes` function to resize my points. I thought it might be a good idea to extract the sample sizes used in `fun.y=mean` and create a new class that could be inputted into `size`, however I am not sure how to do that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

**EDIT**

Here's my data for reference:

```
Plant Branch Pod_B Flow_Miss Pod_A Flow_T Trt     Dmg
<int>  <dbl> <int>     <int> <int>  <dbl> <fct> <int>
1     1   1.00     0        16    20  36.0  Early     1
2     1   2.00     0         1    17  18.0  Early     1
3     1   3.00     0         0    17  17.0  Early     1
4     1   4.00     0         3    14  17.0  Early     1
5     1   5.00     5         2     4  11.0  Early     1
6     1   6.00     0         3     7  10.0  Early     1
7     1   7.00     0         4     6  10.0  Early     1
8     1   8.00     0        13     6  19.0  Early     1
9     1   9.00     0         2     7   9.00 Early     1
10     1  10.0      0         2     3   5.00 Early     1
```

EDIT 2:

Here is a graph of what I'm trying to achieve with proportional sizing by sample size n per `Trt` (treatment), where the mean is calculated per `Trt` and `Branch` number. I'm wondering if I should make `Branch` a categorical variable.

[Plot without Proportional Sizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZeHx.jpg)

Comment: Easier way would be to calculate stats before ggplot2. Can you post your data?

Comment: @PoGibas Of course! I've edited it to the original post.

Comment: What would be the `x` axis value? also `mean`?

Comment: @missuse The x-axis value is the `Branch`, mean is `Flow_T` based on the `Branch` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you would like to scale the size of points based on the number of points per `Trt` group.

How about something like this? Note that I appended your sample data, because `Trt` contains only `Early` entries.

```
df %>%
    group_by(Trt) %>%
    mutate(ssize = n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Branch, y = Flow_T, colour = Trt, size = ssize)) +
        geom_point();
```

[image]

Explanation: We group by `Trt`, then calculate the number of samples per group `ssize`, and plot with argument `aes(...., size = ssize)` to ensure that the size of points scale with `sscale`. You don't need the `group` aesthetic here.

---

### Update

To scale points according to the mean of `Flow_T` per `Trt` we can do:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Trt) %>%
    mutate(
        ssize = n(),
        mean.Flow_T = mean(Flow_T)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Branch, y = Flow_T, colour = Trt, size = mean.Flow_T)) +
        geom_point();
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text =
    "Plant Branch Pod_B Flow_Miss Pod_A Flow_T Trt     Dmg
1     1   1.00     0        16    20  36.0  Early     1
2     1   2.00     0         1    17  18.0  Early     1
3     1   3.00     0         0    17  17.0  Early     1
4     1   4.00     0         3    14  17.0  Early     1
5     1   5.00     5         2     4  11.0  Early     1
6     1   6.00     0         3     7  10.0  Early     1
7     1   7.00     0         4     6  10.0  Early     1
8     1   8.00     0        13     6  19.0  Early     1
9     1   9.00     0         2     7   9.00 Early     1
10     1  10.0      0         2     3   5.00 Early     1
11     1  10.0      0         2     3   20.00 Late     1", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I was not able to create the graph I was hoping for. To clarify, I am trying to size the scatter points proportional to the calculated mean, where the mean was created by `fun.y=mean`. This is why I used `stat_summary` (I think).

So, the sample size n is based off `Trt` and the `Branch` number. Perhaps I should treat the `Branch` as a categorical variable? I've included a graph in my original post to show what I'm attempting to do... except the proportional sizing is not included.

Comment: @Cam.S The mean of what? The mean of `Branch`, the mean of `Flow_t`? Again, I would advise against your `stat_summary` approach; it is much cleaner to calculate any summary statistics on the level of the data, and then just hand-over the `data.frame` to your plotting function and pull out the relevant aesthetics.

Comment: It would be the mean of `Flower_T`. How would I calculate the summary statistics beforehand?

I apologize for my lack of foresight... I am relatively new to R and was suggested to use `stat_summary`

Comment: @Cam.S I have updated my answer, please take a look. Again, no need for `stat_summary`; it is cleaner to calculate any data manipulations on the data first, and then pass the data to `ggplot` and map the relevant aesthetics.

Comment: I somehow managed to write "proportional to the calculated mean" in my first comment, but I mean't to say sample size as originally mentioned in my question. Nevertheless, your solution was VERY helpful and I now understand to use `mutate` as well as other manipulations before applying `ggplot`. Cheers.

Comment: No worries @Cam.S; glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Using [@Maurits Evers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530970/maurits-evers)'s help, I created my desired graph by making `Branch` a factor. The following is my code as well as my intended graph:

```
branch1$Branch <- as.factor(branch1$Branch)
branch1$Flow_T <- as.numeric(branch1$Flow_T)
branch1 %>%
  group_by(Trt, Branch) %>%
  mutate(ssize = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Branch, y = Flow_T, colour = Trt)) +
  stat_summary(aes(size=ssize), fun.y=mean, geom="point")
```

[Final Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PruG7.jpg)

Comment: Please see my comment below.

Comment: This is great but to better represent the weighting you should make the area of the points proportional to sample size… IE aes(size=sqrt(size))